# Php postgresql error, prepared statement already exists

Tags: php, postgresql

Am getting an error of prepared statement "my_query7" already exists, i call this function each time a user tries to update table leader_info in the database, i have gone through the documentation for pg_prepare and i don't understand what is meant by it should only be run once. code snippets will be of help. Thanks.

```
 function add_leader_country($user_id,$l_country)
 {
   global $connection;
   $query = pg_prepare($connection,"my_query7","update leader_info set l_country = $1 where user_id = $2 and status < 9"); 
$result = pg_execute($connection,"my_query7",array($l_country,$user_id));
if(!$result)
{
  echo pg_last_error($connection);
} 
else 
{
  echo "Records created successfully\n";
}
$row = pg_affected_rows($result);
return $row;



 }
```

Comment: *"i call this function each time a user tries to **add** a new leader to the database"* - Add or update? Your query shows as being an update, not an insert.

Comment: So.. um... where is `my_query8`? You've provided `my_query7`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare execute does not permit duplicate naming, so that is your error. 
A query should only be prepared once, for example, in a cycle for the preparation state must be set out of the for and its execution in the for.

```
 $result=$pg_prepare($connection,"my_query7",$query);
    for($id=1;$id<3;$id++){
      $result=pg_execute($connection,"my_query7",array($l_country,$user_id));
       ...
    }
```

In your case using a functio that use the prepare and execute multiple times it's a problem.

What are you trying to accomplish with this function dispatches more code like where you are calling the function. This way I might be able to help you.

If you want to use functions I would use this method

Exemple from https://secure.php.net

```
<?php
function requestToDB($connection,$request){
    if(!$result=pg_query($connection,$request)){
        return False;
    }
    $combined=array();
    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $combined[]=$row;
    }
    return $combined;
}
?>

<?php
$conn = pg_pconnect("dbname=mydatabase");

$results=requestToDB($connect,"select * from mytable");

//You can now access a "cell" of your table like this:
$rownumber=0;
$columname="mycolumn";

$mycell=$results[$rownumber][$columname];
var_dump($mycell);
```

If you whant to use preaper and execute functions try to create a function that creates the preparations only once in a session. Do not forget to give different names so that the same error does not occur. I tried to find something of the genre and did not find. If you find a form presented here for others to learn. If in the meantime I find a way I present it.

Comment: The method i posted above is one out of many methods, i intend using the method to update a table in the database each time a user provides country details. Multiple users are involved.

Comment: You try to create a function that creates the preparations only once in a session. Do not forget to give different names so that the same error does not occur.

Comment: Hi, I found something that could allow you to use the function as you were using it. I'm not sure if it works. Give it a try and say if it solves the problem. Pg_free_result ($result);

Comment: You can try to close the conection: pg_close($conn);

Comment: Thanks @Jose Marques, i had to drop pg_prepare() for pg_query_params(), pg_prepare() doesn't work the way i thought(with repeated calls).